# Knockout.js and Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, knockout.js

I have a Jquery Mobile and phonegap application. I use:

```
   Jquery Mobile (1.3.1)
   jquery (1.9.1)
   Phonegap (2.8.0)
```

I have been asked to use knockout.js in the application. I am totally new to `knockout.js` and am still trying to understand how it works.

I will have to send ajax requests with `JSON` data and the responses will be `JSON` objects. I used to use for loops to handle the JSON objects and everything worked great. I'm just a little apprehensive on how to het all this to work with knockout.js.

Can anyone please give me suggestions on how to go about with this new knockout.js. I have very limited time (about 1 week), to understand how to get all this to work.

Or do you suggest sticking with what we know and use jquery and jquery mobile.

Comment: Hello @BetRob. You can check [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) and the [official site](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html). Please only ask questions when you have a real problem with your code. Good luck :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/with-binding-magic-writing-single-page-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-knockoutjs/) too. Although it is not basic.

Answer (score 0):

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Knockout doesn’t force you to use any one particular technique to load or save data. 
You can use the one that you normally use

```
$.getJSON("/some/url", function(data) { 
    // Now use this data to update your view models, 
    // and Knockout will update your UI automatically 
})

var data = /* Your data in JSON format - see below */;
$.post("/some/url", data, function(returnedData) {
    // This callback is executed if the post was successful     
})
```